# I added multiple ssh accounts, and then when connecting to a remote serve, I got a permission denied

Tags: ssh

I added multiple Github accounts, and added a config file to identify two different account, but I don't know if is this reason, when I wanna using password connect to the remote serve, I got a permission denied.

I have tried to set `PubkeyAuthentication yes` at 'sshd_config', and tried restarted sshd, but all not works.

`ssh -v root@10.2xx.1xx.1xx`:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxx/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.2xx.1xx.1xx [10.2xx.1xx.1xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.2xx.1xx.1xx:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:fxj6m86Rty2c+dOO9KR6WLxZ4ikAOd8AVg/z/diVlto
debug1: Host '10.2xx.1x.1xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa_private
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@10.2xx.1xx.1xx's password:
```

Did i have a way both reserve the multiple accounts and can connect to remote serve.

Comment: Seems like your server doesn't accept your key. Did you append your SSH marshaled public key to `authorized_keys` file in `~/.ssh` folder?

Comment: I don't understand, I can't find a `authorized_keys` file in ~/.ssh, and my Github accounts which need public keys works well, and I just want to connect to a remote server using password, did I need to add keys?@Berkant